# Do Tensorflow Serving run inference with cache?

Tags: docker, jmeter, tensorflow-serving, stress-testing

When I serve my TF model with tensorflow serveing, **on version 2.1.0**, through docker, I perform a stress testing with Jmeter. There is a problem. **TPS will hit 4400 by testing with single data, while it only reach 1700 with multiple data in a txt file.** The model is BiLSTM which I've trained without any cache setting. The experiments all perform in local server rather than through network.

#### Metrics:

In single data task, I set running HTTP request with identical data without interval by 30 request threads for 10 minutes.

- TPS: 4491
- CPU occupied: 2100%
- 99% Latancy Line(ms): 17
- error rate: 0

In multiple data task, I set running HTTP request with reading a txt file, a dataset with 9740000 different examples, by 30 request threads.

- TPS: 1711
- CPU occupied: 2300%
- 99% Latancy Line(ms): 42
- error rate: 0

#### Hardware：

- CPU cores:12
- processor: 24
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4214 CPU @ 2.20GHz

Is there a cache in Tensorflow Serving?

Why is TPS with single data testing larger thrice than with various data testing in stress testing task?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. Request threads reading the same file needs to wait for which cost CPU for running Jmeter.

Comment: But do you have an answer to your initial question: do TFS run inference with cache?